# How do you get the value from a TVML textField?

Tags: apple-tv

I am trying to figure out how to get the value from the textField in TVML using TVJS but I haven't found any documentation on it yet and I don't want to wait around for the documentation to be updated. There isn't really any patterns for binding to input since I'm sure this is a seldom use case other than logging into a service. I guess I could parse the Xml but that seems super hacky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out myself. I had to use the callback from the select event object and then pass the text element into a function to handle the event.

```
function template() {
    var template = "<document><formTemplate><textField id="email">Your email</textField><footer><button><text>Submit</text></button></footer></formTemplate></document>";
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(template , "application/xml");
    var email = doc.getElementById("email");
    doc.addEventListener("select", function() { submit(email); });
}

function submit(textField) {
    var keyboard textField.getFeature('Keyboard');
    var email = keyboard.text;
}
```

Once I had the node I used the apple TVJS function getFeature('Keyboard') to get the text value from this object.

Comment: Please illustrate with code if you are gonna answer (even if its your own question)

Comment: To anyone searching for a solution take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808960/how-to-get-the-node-and-keyboard-reference-of-tvml-textfield-in-tvjs) SO post

Comment: Cleaned up my answer and added a code sample. I also created a TS definition file to help with navigating the AppleTVJS api. https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/appletvjs

Answer (score 0):

this solution doesn't work for me by some reason, but I found another one:

```
 var sender = event.target;
 var formTemplate = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
 var children = formTemplate.childNodes;
 var textField = children.item(1); // replace "1" with the index of "textField" element in your template                                                                                        
 var inputValue = textField.getFeature("Keyboard").text;
```