# How to get the node and keyboard reference of TVML textField in TVJS?

Tags: javascript, apple-tv, tvos, tvml

Someone asked the same question here [How do you get the value from a TVML textField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655635/how-do-you-get-the-value-from-a-tvml-textfield) but didn't explain the full answer and my comment there was edited, suggesting me to ask a brand new question. Here it is...

Can anyone help understand how to best get a reference to the `textField` node and its keyboard value from TVML? Right now I'm using this code below in `Presenter.js` to get to the `textField` once the user clicks the `Done` button in the template displaying the form & keyboard, but still get

> ITML : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'textField.getFeature') - .../js/Presenter.js

when I use `getFeature("Keyboard")`:

```
load: function(event) {  
var self = this,  
    ele = event.target,  
    templateURL = ele.getAttribute("template"),  
    presentation = ele.getAttribute("presentation"),  
    videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL");  

if (templateURL && (event.type == "select")) {  
    var formTemplate = ele.parentNode.parentNode; // that should give me <formTemplate> element  
    var children = formTemplate.childNodes;  
    var textField = children[1]; // which is the second element in <formTemplate><banner></banner><textField></textField>...  
    var keyboard = textField.getFeature("Keyboard"); // this raises the ITML Error...  
    ...........................
```

---

UPDATE:

I found the solution by looking into [accessing elements by traversing XML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_nodelist_item.asp):

```
var formTemplate = ele.parentNode.parentNode; // your formTemplate button  
var children = formTemplate.childNodes;  
var textField = children.item(1); // replace "1" with the index of "textField" element in your template  
var keyboard = textField.getFeature("Keyboard"); // get the textField's Keyboard element  
var userValue = keyboard.text; // the value entered by the user on the Apple TV keyboard
```

Answer (score 2):

How about starting at the document's root? Use `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementByTagName` or `getElementById` to access the `textField`.

```
var doc = navigationDocument.documents[navigationDocument.documents.length-1];
var textField = doc.getElementByTagName("textField")

var value = textField.getFeature("Keyboard").text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed the self explained solution,
I'm adding to be complete the text on change callback:

```
var keyboard = textField.getFeature("Keyboard");
keyboard.onTextChange = function () {
  console.log("onTextChange "+keyboard.text)
}
```

And supposed that the formTemplate is like

```
<formTemplate>
    <banner>
      <title>${formTitle}</title>
      <description class="longDescriptionLayout">${formDescription}</description>
    </banner>
    <textField>${formPlaceholder}</textField>
    <footer>
      <button id="pairingCodeInput">
        <text>Confirm</text>
      </button>
    </footer>
  </formTemplate>
```

in the `Presenter` class I would add to handle more selectors something like:

```
if ((event.type == "select")) { // item selected
    if (itemId == "pairingCodeInput") { // form input
        var formTemplate = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
        var children = formTemplate.childNodes
        var textField = children.item(1)
        var keyboard = textField.getFeature("Keyboard")
        keyboard.onTextChange = function() {
            console.log("onTextChange " + keyboard.text)
        }
        var userValue = keyboard.text
        console.log("Entered " + userValue)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
xmlElem.item(i)
```

instead of

```
xmlElem.item[i]
```